# Mixed programming failed in release but succeeded in debug

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, fortran, release, mixed-mode

In my compiler a function named "func" will be renamed as _FUNC@*  after compiling in fortran. And if a c code use _stdcall calling     convention, then the function name, e.g. Ab, will be renamed as
_Ab@*    after compiling. So this can lead to a concise method for mixed       programming between fortran and c. The following is my code.
source1.f90

```
program main
implicit none
call subprint()
read(*,*)
endprogram
```

ccode.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  void _stdcall SUBPRINT()
{printf("hello the world\n");}
#ifdef _cplusplus
}
```

My platform is win 7 and vs2010 is used. Compliler is visual c++. The ccode.c will generate a .lib and the fortran project will use it. And this will run successfully in debug mode. But when I changed the project into release mode, errors would occur. The errors are the main function in Source1.f90 can not find out the _SUBPRINT. Note that I have already generated the .lib in the release mode and add it to the fortran project.

Another method for mixed programming is using _cdecl calling convention. The following codes will run successfully in both debug and release mode.

```
module abc
  interface
    subroutine subprint()
      !dec$ attributes C,alias:'_subprint'::subprint
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module

program main
  use abc
   implicit none
   call subprint()
   read(*,*)
endprogram
```

Here is the c code. The default calling convention is just _cdecl.

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
 void  subprint()
 {printf("hello the world\n");}
#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Why this happened? I put all these codes in the same solution. So the configuration is the same.

Comment: `We all know that a function named "func" will be renamed as _FUNC@* after compiling in fortran` NO! NO! NO! This is highly compiler and system specific.

Comment: Also, as I have told you previously, VS2010 is an EDITOR, you have to say which COMPILER do you use!

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. In fact, I am not an engineer. Sorry for saying such arbitrary judgment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that your C function is `SUBPRINT` not `subprint`, that DOES matter even inside C.

Second, you should use `__cplusplus`, not `_cplusplus`

Third, just use modern Fortran for interoperability with C:

c.cc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  void subprint(){
   printf("hello the world\n");
  }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

f.f90:

```
program main
implicit none

interface
  subroutine subprint() bind(C,name="subprint")
  end subroutine
end interface

call subprint()
read(*,*)
endprogram
```

`gfortran c.cc f.f90`

```
./a.out
hello the world
```

Comment: I have already solved it. Fortran->external procedure->calling convention->cvf

Comment: Be sure to have a problem with the next compiler change.